# Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps map is not updated

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps 3.3.0. The map is only partially loaded, i.e. when scrolling left / right, it is not updated, but only the grid is shown. What could be the reason

Answer (score 1):

The question is cleared. The key flew in the google console and the lines did not work out

```
<uses-permission android: name = "mypackage.android.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" /> <permission android: name = "mypackage.android.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android: protectionLevel = "signature" />
```

in AndroidManifest, but the map was partially loaded.

Just a new indication of the assembly name and SHA-1 fingerprint helped

Comment: Could you please mark  your reply as answered so that it will help others who have similar problem? Thanks in advance.